# Wait for inner directive to compile before calling api function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im following the below pattern where i need to call the child directive's API function from the parent directive

Following is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gauravsoni/qykbfvy0/2/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function(){

})

myApp.directive('d1', function() {
    return {
        controller: function($scope,$element) {
            console.log('d1 - ctrl');
          // $scope.api.awesomeApi();
            $scope.clicked = function(){
                $scope.api.awesomeApi();
            }
        },
        link: function(scope,ele,attr) {
           //scope.api.awesomeApi();
           console.log('d2 - link');
        },
        template:"This is D1<button ng-click='clicked()'>Clicked</button> <div d2 apifn='api'></div>"
    }
});
myApp.directive('d2', function() {
    return {
        scope:{
            apifn:"="
        },
        controller: function($scope,$element) {
           console.log('d2 - ctrl');
           $scope.isvisible = true;
           function awesomeApiFn(){
            console.log('api function is called');
           }
           $scope.apifn = {
            awesomeApi:awesomeApiFn
           } 
        },
        link: function(scope,ele,attr) {
          console.log('d2 - link');
        },
        template:'<div ng-if="isvisible"><p>Hello</p><h3>WORLD</h3><div>'
    }
});
```

The problem is when i call `$scope.api.awesomeApi()` during the loading of the d1 controller it shows undefined which is correct , but when i call awesomeApi() in the link of d1 it is supposed to work as link of d1 is getting called after the link of d2 but its not working and i again get undefined.

How can i make sure sure that the api function in d1 are only called after the d2 is finished compiling ? Or is there some better pattern to reveal the directive d2's API functions.

Comment: Post the html where you are using these directives

Answer (score 0):

Consider injecting the d1 controller into the child directive and add the api object during the linking phase ([example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qykbfvy0/3/)):

```
myApp.directive('d1', function() {
    return {
        controller: function($scope,$element) {
            var self = this;
            console.log('d1 - ctrl');
            $scope.clicked = function(){
                self.api.awesomeApi();
            }
        },
        // ctrl.api has been set by child directive's link function
        link: function(scope,ele,attr,ctrl) {
           console.log('d1 - link');
           ctrl.api.awesomeApi();
        },
        template:"This is D1<button ng-click='clicked()'>Clicked</button> <div d2></div>"
    }
});

myApp.directive('d2', function() {
    return {
        // require both controllers
        require: ['^d1', 'd2'],
        controller: function($scope,$element) {
           console.log('d2 - ctrl');
           $scope.isvisible = true;
           function awesomeApiFn(){
            console.log('api function is called');
           }
           // put api object on d2 (this) controller
           this.api = {
            awesomeApi:awesomeApiFn
           } 
        },
        link: function(scope,ele,attr,ctrls) {
          var d1Controller = ctrls[0];
          var d2Controller = ctrls[1];
          console.log('d2 - link');
          // update d1Controller to have d2Controller api
          d1Controller.api = d2Controller.api;
        },
        template:'<div ng-if="isvisible"><p>Hello</p><h3>WORLD</h3><div>'
    }
});
```

I think the problem you are seeing is that the $scope.api object is not trued up until another digest cycle due to the 2 way binding from isolate scope. Another option to communicate from parent to child controller is to $broadcast an event from parent scope. Child scope will handle this and delegate to its api function. Do what makes the most sense for your use case. If d1 and d2 are dependent upon each other, probably go with controller injection (example above). If you want them more loosely coupled, go with eventing. From your example, it seems like they belong together (as you are accessing objects between the two).